# How to change Pycharm auto-format?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am using pycharm as my editor in python. One problem I have with it is that whenever I press autoformat (command+option+l), it causes some of my code lines to be broken into several lines. For example, this code:

```
        percentage_optimal_arm = self.main_program.compute_percentage_optimal_arm(algorithm_instance.chosen_arm_history,self.k_value_of_arms_list)
```

breaks to this:

```
percentage_optimal_arm = self.main_program.compute_percentage_optimal_arm(
                algorithm_instance.chosen_arm_history, self.k_value_of_arms_list)
```

This is really annoying as my screen is big enough to include the whole line and it makes my whole code looks ugly. Is there a way to increase the limit for breaking lines in pycharm?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change **Hard Wrap value** at **Settings > Editor > Code Style > Python**

**Default** is **120** line spaces. Change it your desired value ex: 180

[image]